# Cannot load gapi.client.drive in Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to use `gapi.client.drive` to access google drive, however, Angular told me `gapi` is not defined.

package.json:

```
"@types/gapi": "^0.0.35",
"@types/gapi.auth2": "^0.0.46",
"@types/gapi.client.drive": "^3.0.0",
```

tsconfig.app.json:

```
"types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2", "gapi.client"]
```

My TS file:

```
console.log(gapi);
```

Even a console.log() reports gapi is not defined, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the **`Google platform API script`** in index.html

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! One more question, can I include this file with webpack?